# How to calculate this principal value? The numeric answer is amazing to me.

Tags: cauchy-principal-value

I need to calculate the following principal value:
$$
    PV\int_{\pi/a}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2-x_0^2} cos(\sqrt{x^2-(\pi/a)^2}r)\frac{\sqrt{x_0^2-(\pi/a)^2}}{\pi\sqrt{x^2-(\pi/a)^2}}dx
$$
At first I thought there was no analytical answer to it, but when I did the numerical calculation, it turns out that the answer is highly identical to 
$$
-sin(\sqrt{x_0^2-(\pi/a)^2}r)/2
$$
Can anyone tell me how to analytically prove this result? Thank you!